# Merge 1st and Second Row, 3rd and 4th Row and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Lets say I have table with rows,

```
Id  Value
----------
1    a
1    b
1    c
1    d
1    e
1    f
```

and the expected result should be,

```
Id  Value1   Value2
-------------------
1    a        b
1    c        d
1    e        f
```

I am very confused here.

Comment: The rows should be ordered by something. Value?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yes off course.

Comment: And what's the criteria for the order then?. What happens if `ID` changes value?

Comment: @Lamak I have where Id=SomeValue always

Comment: @Lamak ORDER BY Value

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yeah, op did, why?

Comment: Yes in DEV I have 2014 but prod have 2005.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz No, ROW_NUMBER is available from SQL Server 2005

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz please don't delete your answer. It works

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz the msdn pages show only 2008+ because those (2008 and following) are the supported versions. There are (archived) pages for 2005 but they are only accessible via direct links. Lamak is right, `ROW_NUMBER()` was introdueced in 2005.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, there's definitely a simpler way to do this, but this works:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Value)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 1 THEN Value END) Value1, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 0 THEN Value END) Value2
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Id,
         RN - ((RN - 1) % 2);
```

This is the result:

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ Value1 ║ Value2 ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ a      ║ b      ║
║  1 ║ c      ║ d      ║
║  1 ║ e      ║ f      ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: GROUP BY Id, (RN - 1) / 2 is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS RowNum
  FROM YourTable
)

SELECT 
    c1.id
  , c1.value as Value1
  , c2.value as Value2
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rownum = c2.rownum - 1
WHERE c1.RowNum % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      Id
           ,min(Value)  as Value1
           ,max(Value)  as Value2

from       (select      Id,Value
                       ,(row_number () over 
                            (partition by Id order by Value)+1)/2 as group_id

            from        mytable as t
            ) t

group by    Id      
           ,group_id
```